# Centos/Polkit - allowing user to restart specific service

Tags: centos, service, systemd

I was wondering if anyone had a workaround for the following issue:

I'm on CentOS using systemd v219.

What I want to do is allow a non-root user to restart tomcat, but for this systemd version the action object doesn't seem to have keys defined for 'unit' (let alone for 'verb'), so it seems to be all or nothing. Either I allow that user free use of org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units which lets them restart *any* service or none.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `visudo` and `sudo`?

Comment: The functionality you need in PolicyKit wasn't added to systemd until [version 226](https://serverfault.com/a/841150/126632). So in the interim I'd probably go with sudo as well.