# Is it safe to allow any user to see the status of all services?

Tags: security, sudo

I would like to allow every linux user to see the status of all systemd services.

I created these lines for the /etc/sudoers file:

```
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl is-active *
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled *
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl status *
```

Are there any security risks which I might not see at the moment?

The fact that every linux use can see the status of all services is not a security risk in my case.

Comment: Why sudo in the first place? systemctl can be run by any user, no root necessary. root access is only necessary for start/stop.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thank you very much for this hint. If you write your comment as answer, then I will upvote and accept it.

Comment: Somehow I forgot this question. Well, better late than never.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing this wrong. You should set the policies using polkit, as systemctl binary itself asks the system if user is allowed to perform an operation. E.g.

/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-default.rules:

```
polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    return ["unix-group:wheel"]; });
```

means that any user from the wheel group can do anything (including service stop/start). [There are more extensive examples](https://serverfault.com/a/841150/88173), [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1064616/polkit-systemd-interaction) and [the code itself](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/88ced61bf9673407f4b15bf51b1b408fd78c149d).

Comment: I am doing this wrong?

Comment: Yes, don't use sudo (atomic bomb) for something that is handled natively.

Answer (score 2):

All your listed `systemctl` commands (`status`, `is-enabled`, `is-active`) can be invoked by any regular user, no root necessary.

You don't need sudo here.

Answer (score 1):

it's safe, as long as you are running a recent version of sudo, env_reset is enabled and the usual caveats

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl status` usually invokes `less` which allows you to write the output under any filename and directory by using the built-in command `s`. If invoked via sudo this file will be created as root and can overwrite any existing file, allowing an unprivileged user to cause damages.

To go further, if your `systemctl` output contains valid commands, they can be run as root if this file gets created under `/etc/cron.hourly`, for example.