# Allow non root user to run certain systemd services (not *), without a password by using a polkit rule

Tags: systemd, dbus, policyd

I have a non root user that I need to have able to start/stop/restart a subset of services on my system without prompting for an authorization password. Ideally I would like this done via polkit but will opt for sudo if needed. Anyway, I have seen solutions here that include adding a file to localauthority and adding a .rules file to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` which specifies the service(s) to be ran. I should mention that this is on a CentOS7 system.

However, the localauthority solution was for *all* services, and the .rules file solution (taken from here: [systemd: Grant an unprivileged user permission to alter one specific service](https://serverfault.com/questions/841099/systemd-grant-an-unprivileged-user-permission-to-alter-one-specific-service)) will still prompt for a password, as the "manage-units" action is set to "auth_admin" in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.systemd1.policy`.

Is there any way to have polkit allow a certain user to run certain services with no password? Without needing to give that user wide open privileges for the manage-units action? I basically want conditional manage-unit privileges.

Also something interesting I've noticed: If I run this function

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" && subject.user == "alice")
    {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

It works, albeit for all services. But if I attempt to drill down the services by changing it to this:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        action.lookup("unit") == "example.service" &&
        subject.user == "alice") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

Suddenly it prompts for a password. Not sure why it wouldn't also prompt for a password on the first function, as it's still acting according to the manage-units action.

Comment: [See also](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13340).