# visudo cannot get around systemctl

Tags: systemctl

I've given my user root permission to run systemcl via visudo.

```
# visudo
XXXXXX ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart shiny-server.service
```

After logging out and back in, I run the command:

```
$ /bin/systemctl restart shiny-server.service
```

And get:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'shiny-server.service'.
Authenticating as: XXXXXXX
Password:
```

I'm seeing things on line talking about `polkit` but I'm not sure if that also needs to be configured along with `visudo`. What's required here to prevent a password from being required to run the command as a specified user?

Comment: You aren't using `sudo` to invoke `systemctl`, so it isn't even in the picture.

Comment: If you really wanted to use PolicyKit, see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/841150/126632).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up `sudo` to allow you to run a command without a password, but you didn't actually run the command with `sudo`!

To fix the problem, run the command with `sudo`.

```
sudo /bin/systemctl restart shiny-server.service
```