# sudo user is not allowed to execute systemctl

Tags: linux, sudo, groups, rhel7, systemctl

I'm trying to allow a user to use sudo to manage a custom systemctl service, this however seems to fail and I can't figure out why.

```
[root@testvm sudoers.d]# ll
total 16
-r--r-----. 1 root root 334 Oct  9 15:42 20_appgroup
-r--r-----. 1 root root 104 Sep 17 11:24 98_admins
```

The 'appgroup' contains this;

```
[root@testvm sudoers.d]# cat 20_appgroup
%appgroup    ALL= /usr/bin/systemctl restart test.service, 
/usr/bin/systemctl start test.service, /usr/bin/systemctl stop 
test.service, /usr/bin/systemctl status test.service
```

I have double checked that the user is member of the appgroup, however when this user runs **sudo systemctl start test.service** this results in an error saying;

```
Sorry, user tester is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/systemctl start test' as root on testvm.
```

Any thought on what could be the issue?

Comment: Your sudo config says 'test.service' but you're  starting 'springboot' - is that a typo or a bug?

Comment: That is probably the reason why it's not working for him.

Comment: Additional things to check: is sudo configured to include files from suders.d? Is the user actually in that group (run `id` as the user)?

Comment: Your sudo config says `/usr/bin/systemctl start test.service` but your user ran `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start test`.

Comment: Also, see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/841150/126632) for a way to allow the user to manage a single service _without_ sudo by configuring PolicyKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging sudo issues:

- run `sudo -l` as the user concerned to show which rights are assigned to that user.
- ensure that those rights correspond to the commands you wish to allow,
  commands allowed in your `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d/*` configurations that don't include arguments will be allowed to run with any argument,
  commands allowed that do include arguments in their specification, will only work with those exact arguments, nothing more and nothing less.
- In case group based rights are missing, check with `id <username>` to get a listing of all groups a user belongs to.
- If include files from `/etc/sudoers.d/` don't get loaded:

  - To include those  snippets the main `/etc/sudoers` configuration file need to be configured to load those additional configuration sections with an `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` directive.
    The leading pound # is **not a comment** but part of the directive.
  - The files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` should not have names that in end in `~` or contain a `.` character.
  - The files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` should should be mode 0440 and owned by root:root.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it worked for me

```
tomcat        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl stop tomcat
```