# How to allow PHP exec to reload NGINX

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php, sudo, exec

How can I allow these commands in PHP:

```
$output = exec('sudo nginx -t 2>&1');
$output2 = exec('sudo /usr/sbin/service nginx reload 2>&1');
```

I've looked into `sudo visudo` in the terminal , but it seems like that will give access to **all** sudo commands, when I only need the two above.

I guess the reload one isn't so important, as I can just run a cron job to do that.

I am using NGINX, with Ubuntu 20 + PHP 7

Comment: There's a very [simple polkit-based solution](https://serverfault.com/a/841150/126632) that would avoid sudo but it's not available on Ubuntu (because of a questionable design decision they inherited from Debian). Consider using a Linux distribution not based on Debian.

Comment: So you're running PHP as root? That sounds even worse than a Debian based OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following lines in `/etc/sudoers.d/nginx`:

```
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/nginx -t
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service nginx reload
```

This disables password prompt when running `sudo /usr/sbin/service nginx reload` or the other command when logged in as `www-data`.

This assumes that your PHP is running under `www-data` user.

Comment: Appreciate it, this works! Also, do you think it's much of an issue to allow these commands from a security point? It shouldn't matter that much right, since it's just an nginx reload

Comment: This in itself isn't a security issue. However, if you allow modifying nginx configuration via PHP scripts, then there can be security issues.