# Unable to kill a process by Jenkins : operation not permitted

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins in centos 9 Server. My intention is that Jenkins will kill the existing Java jar process and will restart the new build Jar. previously I have used the same command for centos 8 but after installing Centos 9 I am facing this problem.

```
process=`ps -ef | grep -v awk | awk -e '/java.*iqa/ { print $2 }'`
kill -9 ${process}
```

Below the error message, I am getting. How It can be solved?

```
++ ps -ef
++ grep -v awk
++ awk -e '/java.*iqa./ { print $2 }'
+ process=57623
+ kill -9 57623
/tmp/jenkins15731163701833690666.sh: line 4: kill: (57623) - Operation not permitted
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 0):

`apropos kill errno` and read the manual on the kill system call and the error codes. Operation not permitted is `EPERM`. Per `man 2 kill`

> For  a  process  to  have  permission  to send a signal, it must
> either be privileged (under Linux: have the
> CAP_KILL capability in the user namespace of the target process), or the real or effective user  ID  of  the
> sending  process must equal the real or saved set-user-ID of the target process.

Examine that PID versus jenkins shell and see how the users are different. Also look at SELinux contexts with `ps Z`.  Different  users is in general a good thing, it provides better isolation. In this case, between the deployment tool and the application it installs.

Consider running the application in a service manager. On systemd Linux systems like this, a service unit is a choice. After writing such a unit, you can give the jenkins user [access to manage the unit via PolicyKit rules](https://serverfault.com/a/841150/241174). And of course make the corresponding change to jenkins scripts to run `systemctl` commands to manage the service. Will make the ps and kill commands obsolete with better handling of unit processes.

Moving this into a service manager puts it in control of the user to run as. You go further in hardening and enable `PrivateUsers=` or `DynamicUser=` on this unit, disconnecting the Java app user from the rest of the system entirely. jenkins can still stop and start the service.

The main disadvantage of going with systemd, it is not portable. You will need some other solution for non-Linux systems.