# How can I install application as root and start and stop it as non root?

Tags: bash, shell, centos8

I have a script which will install mysql server, java and then my java application.
I want to create a test user and group testg, the application will start and stop by non-root user (here test user) however the installation will be done as root user. example: service mysqld start/stop will be run as non root user.

I am using centos 8 machine. Is there any way it can be achieved. I tried to give permissions to all files as test:testg.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you consider usage of `sudo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [systemd: Grant an unprivileged user permission to alter one specific service](https://serverfault.com/questions/841099/systemd-grant-an-unprivileged-user-permission-to-alter-one-specific-service)